# How to get a Google Sheet script to skip empty rows?

Tags: image, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to using App Script. I have a script from https://gist.github.com/palumbo/d751841c3e61764f058fb60253bc47fe that downloads images from URLS on the Google sheet to Google Drive. My source sheet has many rows where the URL field is empty. The script stops at an empty cell. How do I tell the script to ignore empty cells in the URL column and continue on to the next row?
Thanks for any help you can provide!

```
function downloadImage() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); 
  let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 

  let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1W4pv0RW7DB_yh8pqChc8YPNyq0ETQ_1m"); 

  for (let i = 0; i < lastRow-1; i++) {
    let url = sheet.getRange(2+i,1).getValue(); 
    let blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob(); 
    folder.createFile(blob); 
  }
}
```

Comment: In order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide the sample input situation of your Spreadsheet?

Comment: For example, If have links to images in column A, in rows 1,2,3,4,6,910. Row 5,7,8 is empty. When I run the script to download the images to the Google Drive folder. it only saves the images up until the 4th row and doesn't save images from 6,9,10 because it stops by the empty cell in row 5.

Comment: Here is a link to the YouTube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6cgMbq_t5V0&t=43s

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your following reply,

> For example, If have links to images in column A, in rows 1,2,3,4,6,910. Row 5,7,8 is empty. When I run the script to download the images to the Google Drive folder. it only saves the images up until the 4th row and doesn't save images from 6,9,10 because it stops by the empty cell in row 5.

In this case, how about the following modified script?

In your script, `getValue()` is used in a loop. In this case, the process cost becomes high. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)

In this modification, first, the cell values are retrieved. And, when the cell value is not empty, the script is run and the downloaded file is created as a file.

#### Modified script:

```js
function downloadImage() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); // or let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1W4pv0RW7DB_yh8pqChc8YPNyq0ETQ_1m");

  // I modidied the below script.
  const values = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + lastRow).getDisplayValues();
  values.forEach(([url]) => {
    if (url && /^https?:\/\/.*$/.test(url)) {
      const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true });
      if (res.getResponseCode() == 200) {
        console.log(`Downloaded from ${url}.`);
        folder.createFile(res.getBlob());
      }
    }
  });
}
```

or, as another approach, the following modification might also be able to be used.

```js
function downloadImage() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); // or let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1W4pv0RW7DB_yh8pqChc8YPNyq0ETQ_1m");

  // I modidied the below script.
  const values = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + lastRow).getRichTextValues();
  values.forEach(([r]) => {
    const url = r.getLinkUrl();
    if (url) {
      const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true });
      if (res.getResponseCode() == 200) {
        console.log(`Downloaded from ${url}.`);
        folder.createFile(res.getBlob());
      }
    }
  });
}
```

#### References:

- [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Hi, this code worked perfectly, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @user22635203 Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
function removingEmptyRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  let vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().map((r,i)=> {r.unshift(i+2);return r;}).filter(r => r.every(c => c !== "")).filter(e => e);
  Logger.log("Empty Rows are 10,20,30,40,50 and I inserted the row numbers into column 1 before removing the blank lines so that those row numbers would be missing.\n\n")
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs).replace('],', '],\n'));
}
```

Empty Rows are 10,20,30,40,50 and I inserted the row numbers into column 1 before removing the blank lines so that those row numbers would be missing.

[[2,44,27,27,3,4,16,49,2,2,34,38,5,27,30,23,30,3,24,41,33,27,42,29,22,16,17],
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